# Is it possible to courier passport of my 3 month old son to the US from India?

Tags: passports, india, us-citizens

My three month old son is a US citizen (born in the US) and we are of Indian origin. He left for India on an entry visa with his mother recently. Before leaving, I prepared all required documentation to apply for Overseas Citizen of India (OCI) card in the US for him. Now I need his US passport, which is with him in India, to apply for OCI in the US.

I thought I will ask someone to bring his passport instead of him coming here, but now I found that it will be illegal to carry another person's passport internationally. Are there any legal options available without him travelling that can get his passport to the US?

---

> **India Import Restrictions**
>   ...
>
> - Indian Passports are prohibited for carriage by anyone except the holder of the passport. Non-Indian Passports from UN Commission, High Commissions & Consulates are acceptable.
>     ...
> - Passports
>     ...

- [India Prohibited and Restricted Items | FedEx Cross Border](https://crossborder.fedex.com/us/assets/prohibited-restricted/india/index.shtml)
- [Canada Post - Canada Postal Guide - International Destination Listing](https://www.canadapost.ca/tools/pg/manual/PGIntDestDetails-e.asp?table=tblCountry&txtLetter=IN)

Comment: I just spoke with FedEx customer care, they said that India will not allow any country's passport to cross the border without that person https://crossborder.fedex.com/us/assets/prohibited-restricted/india/index.shtml

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141560/discussion-on-question-by-kalyan-kumar-is-it-possible-to-courier-passport-of-my).

Comment: @KalyanKumar it would be nice toe learn the outcome of this...

Comment: By rule, it's illegal. But practically someone taking your infants passports outside of India won't really have a problem. Just keep it in that someone's hand baggage. Further, if that person is a family that'll make it even more genuine. And at the end even if someone did stop the carrier, prove the genuine intent, it'll be all fine. (we are talking about "India", "Indian" and "infant" here). Now what are rules in US and how they act is a different story.